# MassTransit multiple Consumers

Tags: c#, queue, message-queue, masstransit

I Have one Consumer-A, and i want to create multimple endpoints witj this consumer. For companies that can be added at runtime. Each company should have its own queue. Is it possible to do with MassTransit InMemmory?

Must be something like this

```
Consumer-A(with SomeID-a)
Consumer-A(with SomeID-b)
```

and many other..

And when I sent a message to the queue it was processed by the exact consumer (only 1 concurrent)

I`ve tried this

```
await using var provider = new ServiceCollection()
            .AddMassTransit(x =>
            {
                x.AddConsumer<ConsumerServiceA>()
                    .Endpoint(e =>
                    {
                        e.Name = "endpint-service";
                        e.Temporary = false;
                        e.ConcurrentMessageLimit = 1;

                        e.InstanceId = SomeId-a;
                    });
            })
            .BuildServiceProvider();
```

I run it when new company created

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it by this

```
        var consumer = new ConsumerA();
        _bus = Bus.Factory.CreateUsingInMemory(cfg =>
        {
            cfg.ConcurrentMessageLimit = 1;
        });
        _bus.ConnectReceiveEndpoint("queue-a", x =>
        {
            x.Consumer(() => consumer);
        });
```